# C#. Получение следующего элемента ConcurrentDictionary при каждом вызове функции

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем доброго времени суток. 
Каждый вызов функции должен изменять индексатор и указывать по нему следующий элемент словаря (ConcurrentDictionary>), и так по кольцу.
Содержимое словаря может активно меняться в параллельных потоках, а чтение циклическое фоновым процессом.

Требование к перфомансу тоже есть, так как таких фоновых процессов больше 100 штук и работает это в asp net core 2.0 под Rasbery Pi.

ProcessAsync - вызываться в цикле каждые 100мс.

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Func<CancellationToken, Task>> _cycleTimeFuncDic;

private int indexCycleFunc = 0;
protected override async Task ProcessAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    if (_cycleTimeFuncDict != null && !_cycleTimeFuncDict.IsEmpty)
    {
        //нужно безопасно (для Concurrent) извлекать каждый следующий элемент из ConcurrentDictionary
        indexCycleFunc++;
    }      
}
```

Приходит на ум использовать только `ToArray()` для обращения по `indexCycleFunc`

```
var f= _cycleTimeFuncDict.ToArray()[indexCycleFunc];
```

Но это нужно делать на каждом вызове функции и как это отразится на перфомансе?
Если со словарем не получается, может использовать другие Concurrent коллекции на которых легко реализовать кольцевой буфер?

Или же в начале работы со словарем получить `Enumerator`,  `_cycleTimeFuncDict.GetEnumerator()`. А внутри функции вызывать `MoveNext()` и `Current`?

ДОБАВЛЯЮ КОД ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ Enumerator

```
 protected override async Task ProcessAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
   {
        try
        {
            if (_cycleTimeFuncDict != null && !_cycleTimeFuncDict.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (_enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var cycleFunc = _enumerator.Current.Value;
                    await cycleFunc(stoppingToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    _enumerator.Dispose();
                    _enumerator = _cycleTimeFuncDict.GetEnumerator();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Fatal($"HostingBackgroundTransport.ProcessAsync {ex}");
        }
    }
```

Что если вот так перечислять словарь? Метод Reset он не поддерживает, поэтому пришлось пере создавать энумератор заново, когда коллекция 1 раз пройдена.
Какие тут могут быть тонкости?

Comment: Порядок элементов в словаре не гарантирован. Поэтому понятие "следующий" не имеет смысла. При вставке/удалении элемента их порядок может поменяться.

Comment: Что именно другие потоки делают с этой коллекцией? Добавляют/удаляют элементы или только изменяют свойства уже имеющихся элементов?

Comment: И нужен ли другим потокам быстрый поиск в коллекции?

Comment: Если ключ новый, то добавленный элемент добавится в конец. Элементы только добавляются и удаляются

Comment: Быстрый доступ по ключу не нужен, только перебирать элементы на чтение в отдельном потоке

Comment: Ну, если элементы добавляются в _конец_, и нужен только перебор и извлечение, то подходит очередь `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: я думал насчет ConcurrentQueue, добавлять действительно в конец но удалять из любого места (что требует пересоздание коллекции) и как перечислять? Перечислять можно, извлечь с верхушки и добавить сразу в конец, но оптимально ли это? И ТОТ ЖЕ ВОПРОС ПРО УДАЛЕНИЕ. ПО СУТИ НУЖЕН ConcurrentList который поддерживает index

Comment: Если использовать GetEnumerator()?